# For the n^th dimension, where n is ≥5, there exists only 3 regular convex polytopes proof

Tags: polytopes

A lot of books stated that is true, however, no proof is given. I was wondering if anyone could help me and show me a proof?

Statement: For the n-th dimension, where n is ≥5, there exists only 3 regular convex polytopes

Thank you

Comment: If not meanwhile found already yourself, you'd find a proof within "Regular Polytopes" by Coxeter.